# Synchronize text area in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I am creating a simple web application in which whatever the client types on textarea field also appears
on the server side textarea field at the same time.

***Imagine it as 2 tabs In one tab user writes on text area and on the other tab user sees the whatever the user has typed at the same time.***

Below is the two jsp files code snippet

**client.jsp**

```
 <%
code=request.getParameter("code_area");
out.print(code);
        try
        {

        File file=new File("code");
        if(file.exists())
        {
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bw.write(code);
        bw.close();

        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        %>
<form action="client.jsp">
<textarea name="code_area"> <%=code%> <textarea>
</form>
```

**server.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Server</title>
    <%@page import="java.io.*"%>
    <script>
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1000);
       </script>
</head>
<body>

    <%
        InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("code"));
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(reader);
        String s;
        while((s=in.readLine())!=null)
        out.print(s);
        %>

</body>
</html>
```

In other Words whatever the user types on the textarea field in the client side appears  on the server side at the same time.

The solution that i thought for this problem ..

I created a common file so that whatever user types on textarea in client gets saved in the file and the server side reads from the text-file at the same time.

But sadly i am not able to code it..Because of the problems i am facing in this ..

Everytime i save a file the cursor in the textarea gets to the beginning of the line which i dont want to happen...?

In order to save the data  into text file i need to click on submit button ...Auto submit 
which i tried from this example http://www.formget.com/javascript-auto-submit-form/#  is not working ....

Can somebody help me to tackle this problem ??
Any help would be highly appreciated ...

Comment: First off server-side code does not have "textarea"s its just code its not HTML. I am assuming you want text from an input to be saved instantly in a text file with every character entered.

Comment: its not the server-side ..Its someone sitting on the other side who wants to see what the user types on the client is visible to him at the same time

Comment: If you are trying to create a chat app then why wouldn't you just say that. Or better yet just google it there are a thousand examples online on how to create a chat app.

Comment: Imagine it as 2 tabs In one tab user writes on text area and on the other tab user sees the whatever the user has typed at the same time

Comment: In chat app you need to click on send or Enter to send your chat ...But this application doesnt need this...AUTO SUBMIT

Comment: Nope that still a chat app its just a real-time chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My new understanding (through comments) of the question is... There is a teacher who wants to see all the imputs of the students in real time, each student has 1 input area and the teacher has an display of each students input but can not edit them.

We will create 2 HTML documnet sand 2 PHP APIs. The first HTML document is for the student to enter their name and then a text area for them to enter an answer. The second HTML documnet will be for the teacher to view all the answers. The first API will be for the students to submit their answer (after each keypress ~real time). And the second API will be for the teacher to retrieve all the students answers (with a small refresh interval to simulate real time without having to use WebSockets).

Also you should create a directory/folder within this directory/folder named "answers" and if you are are Mac/Linux give permissions 0777 to the "answers" directory/folder.

**Student.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Student</title>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#answer").on("keyup", function (e) {
        $.post("sendAnswer.php", {name: $("#name").val(), answer: e.target.value}, function(){console.log(arguments)});
      });
      $("#name").on("blur", function(e){
        if(e.target.value.length>0)
          $("#answer").attr("disabled", false);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <label for='name'>Who are you?</label>
  <input type='text' id='name' Placeholder='Name' />
  <br><br>
  <textarea id='answer' placeholder='Answer' disabled></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**Teacher.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Teacher</title>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      refresh_answers();
      window.setInterval(refresh_answers, 500); // Refresh Every 500ms (0.5 seconds)
    });
    function refresh_answers(){
      $.get("getAnswers.php", function(x){
        x = JSON.parse(x);
        var s = ""; // HTML string
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
          s+="<div><span class='name'>"+x[i].name+"</span><span class='answer'>"+x[i].answer+"</span></div>";
        }
        $("#answers").html(s);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    #answers div {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 256px;
      height: 256px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 16px;
    }
    #answers .name {
      display: block;
      width: 256px;
      height: 56px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
      line-height: 56px;
      font-weight: 700;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    #answers .answer {
      display: block;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='answers'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**sendAnswer.php**

```
<?php
  file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/answers/".$_POST['name'].".txt", $_POST['answer']);
?>
```

**getAnswers.php**

```
<?php
  $answers = glob(dirname(__FILE__)."/answers/*");
  $answers_array = array();
  foreach($answers as $a){
    $answer = array();
    $answer['answer'] = file_get_contents($a);
    $name = explode("/", $a);
    $name = array_pop($name);
    $name = str_replace(".txt", '', $name);
    $answer['name'] = $name;
    array_push($answers_array, $answer);
  }
  print_r(json_encode($answers_array));
?>
```

Comment: you can mess the "refresh interval" for the teacher in line 8 by changing the number ``500`` up or down. This is the number of milliseconds between refreshes, the lower the number the more "real time" the app will feel but will slow down/freeze the browser. The higher the number the "laggier" the app will feel but it not freeze the browser.

Comment: Also this has NO security and could cause major issues for the server. For instance if a student put in ``<script>alert("I Hate You")</script>`` in their "answer" the teach would get a nice surprise and would have no idea who did it. or you can do an injection attack into the PHP itself using by escaping the ``file_put_contents`` and then injecting what they want. So make sure to sanitize the data.

Comment: this is something more amazing then expected ......Thanks a lot @dustin ....your answer deserves more applaud then any other thing .....you made my day man....thank you so much :)

Comment: One bug i found that when i typed <stdio.h> in the textarea it was not visible in the teacher.html......i dont know why that happened

Comment: Even new line is not visible in the textarea in teacher.html... was that a problem of php ???

Comment: What happened is it got translated into an HTML tag and is therefore not displayed. In ``sendAnswer.php`` you should convert the special characters into html special characters using ``htmlspecialchars()``.

Comment: "\n" is not displayed in html so you have to convert it to "<br>" using ``nl2br()``

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with WebSockets but that's way more complicated to set up, but it would be more proper and faster.

For an easy solution (without WebSockets), what you need to do is send an ajax POST request to the server every time the key is pressed, this might be really slow but it should work. Here I will be using jQuery on the client side and PHP on the server side.

**HTML**

```
<input id='input' />
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
// After DOM ready
$(function(){ 
  // When a character is entered in the input
  $("#input").on("keyup", function(e){ 
    // Send the inputs value to the server
    $.post("saveInput.php" {text: e.target.value});
  });
});
```

**PHP** (saveInput.php)

```
<?php
    file_put_contents("input.text", $_POST['text']);
?>
```

This should save their input into a text file called `input.txt` on the server every time they enter a character in the input.

Comment: your solution looks promising .. Give me sometime to verify it

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this plugin I think it will do what you want:

https://togetherjs.com/

Comment: togetherjs plugin is filled with lots of bugs

Comment: Bugs found when i ran that in google chrome although on mozilla it is pretty stable

Comment: Actual bugs or console errors? Because if you think a console error is a bug then dont look at facebook or Google or any major websites console ir they all have hundreds of "bugs"

Comment: Somehow your hint of togetherjs beautifully qualifies for the answer ...

Thanks @dustin

Comment: In togetherjs there is a common textarea that everyones access...But in my application there is an admin with lot of users who are independtly accessing textarea ...i wanted admin to access textarea of any user and see what he is typing...
If you can give me some hint as how can achieve it i will be more excited

Comment: So you are saying that only one person can edit it and others can only watch?

Comment: just reverse of what you wrote ....every person has its own textarea and an admin can watch any person textarea..

Comment: Oh ok so then the admin's page will have to have many many text areas, one for every user and each uses has their own?

Comment: think of it as an online examination system ...where the teacher can watch any student textarea in real time....

Comment: Ok I'll make another answer then using the ajax method similar to my last answer